# WSO2 Idenity Server Initial Setup for Cloud Host

Tags: redirect, wso2, server, saml

After a fresh install, I'm able to login into the https://host:9443/carbon URL, but not able to register a local user through dashboard due to an 
immediate redirect onto the URL https://localhost:9443/samlsso.

Which files needs to be configured to reflect the valid hostname? Are 
there any digital certificates required to secure SSL that host and where is the place to store it?

Thanks in advance for hints how to setup the WSO2 Identity environment.

Regards, 
Claude

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the hostname value for key `IdentityProviderSSOServiceURL` in `repository/conf/security/authenticators.xml` file.

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful information.I now got access to the dashboard screen and subsequent redirects. Wonder why there is no System Property to store the IP hostname and domain to avoid manual .xml updates during ports. Any idea how to make it portable?